# Bluetooth Connection inside VirtualBox (Host: Mac OS X, Guest: Android 7.1)

Tags: macos, virtualbox, android, bluetooth

I need help establishing access to my internal Bluetooth module of a MacBook Air inside an Android 7.1 32bit guest system from VirtualBox.
I have no problems connecting my bluetooth inside an Ubuntu 16.04 64bit virtual system, so in theory it should work. Can someone help me understand why it does not work on the Android system?

When I start the Android machine I can see the bluetooth module in the USB devices and also enable it. In the OS itself however it is not possible to turn Bluetooth on. I cannot find any related solution for that.